# MVVM light toolkit: New Window

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have been searching but I have not been able to find an example that uses MVVM light toolkit that loads a new window. I would like an example that passes between both the parent and child window.

For exmaple I am in my MainWindow.xaml and I want to be able to load a new window, both bring in view at the same time. Not a pop up window.

I am using WPF.

Any examples would be a great help?

Thanks

Comment: What is "loads a new window"? Did you mean "open dialog window"? Or something else?

Comment: @Dennis I mean a new window, not a dialog window.

Comment: you are not being clear ? do you mean opening a new window while closing the one that fired the new window ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an UIService class that will handle the creation/desctrution of new Windows in your application.

For example, take a look at Cinch (http://cinch.codeplex.com/) which propose the following UIServices:

- UI Services Event Logger (Cinch V1 Only)
- MessageBox (Cinch V1 and Cinch V2 WPF/SL)
- Open File (Cinch V1 and Cinch V2 WPF)
- Save File (Cinch V1 and Cinch V2 WPF)
- Popup Window (Cinch V1 and Cinch V2 WPF)
- Child Window (Cinch V2 SL)